# FogBugz Plugin Conversion to URL Trigger

Tags: fogbugz

I am trying to convert a FogBugz plugin as they are being deprecated.

I am trying to convert it to their new URL Trigger.

In the page where I configure the trigger is gives me a number of parameters that can be appended to the url string - happy days!

But, in the "old code" it's making reference to CBug - which has a number of values which don't appears to be available in the trigger configuration page

for example:

in the old code I would be able to get the customer email like this:

```
public void BugCommitAfter(CBug bug, BugAction nBugAction, CBugEvent bugevent, bool fPublic)
{
        bug.sCustomerEmail
}
```

the available parameters in the trigger config page are:

```
Case Events: {AreaID}  {AreaName}  {AssignedToID}  {AssignedToName}  {CaseEventID}  {CaseNumber}  {Category}  {Computer}  {CurrentEstimate}  {DueDate}  {ElapsedTime}  {EmailBCC}  {EmailBodyHtml}  {EmailBodyText}  {EmailCC}  {EmailDate}  {EmailFrom}  {EmailReplyTo}  {EmailSubject}  {EmailTo}  {EventText}  {EventTime}  {EventType}  {FixForID}  {FixForName}  {MilestoneID}  {MilestoneName}  {PersonEditingID}  {PersonEditingName}  {PriorityID}  {PriorityName}  {ProjectID}  {ProjectName}  {ReleaseNotes}  {StatusID}  {StatusName}  {Title}  {Version}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the equivalent of sCustomerEmail?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Trev

**Update:**

Worked out how to get into the XML7 API

from here I can ask for a "case" and ask that "cols" include "sCustomerEmail".

it's still blank.

## dunno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple misunderstanding.

The sCustomerEmail only gets populated if the case has been emailed into fogbugz..

Makes sense really...

Trev